# set object to currently selected chart in excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts

All,

I want to set variable cht to the current chart. I've tried the below code but for some reason it puts an extra "chart " on the name. Is there an alternate way?

```
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObject(ActiveChart.Name)
```

This code doesn't work because it can't find the object with that name.

```
msgbox ActiveChart.Name
```

yields "chart pvtChart1" when the actual name is "pvtChart1". Is there an alternate way to reference the active chart?

I apologize for not correctly formatting the code due to my computer settings that I can't change. Thanks.

-Rik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *chart* appended to the name of chart is the name of worksheet where this chart is placed.

You can retrieve the name of chart like that:

```
MsgBox ActiveChart.Parent.Name
```

---

If you want to set variable `cht` to the current chart you don't need to refer to the collection of charts. You can do it like that:

```
Set cht = ActiveChart.Parent
```

Comment: You're setting the variable to the ChartObject, not to the chart.

Comment: Yes, but this is what @Rik wanted to achieve with this code: `Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObject(ActiveChart.Name)`.

Comment: He said "current chart", but the code was for ChartObject; you did the same. It would be interesting to see how cht was declared.

Answer (score 1):

The Chart is embedded in a shape also known as a ChartObject.

If you want to reference the chart (as I suspect), use this:

```
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ActiveChart
```

If you want to reference the parent chart object:

```
Dim chtob As ChartObject
Set chtob = ActiveChart.Parent
```

The chart is related to the chart object like this:

```
Dim chtob As ChartObject, cht As Chart
Set chtob = ActiveChart.Parent
Set cht = chtob.Chart
```